# Touchpad works in gnome environment, but not in cinnamon?

Tags: 17.10, touchpad, cinnamon, gnome-shell

Installed Cinnamon because gnome was too laggy and taking up too much resources. Synaptics touchpad is not working now, but was working in gnome. 
Already tried reinstalling synaptics drivers with: sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Any other ideas why it isn't working?

Ubuntu 17.10
Laptop: Razer Blade 2017, i7-7700HQ/GTX1060

Comment: Do you still have the same problem if you create a new user then log in as the new user? You can create a new user by running `sudo adduser username` where "username" is the name of the new user you want.

Comment: Yes, just tried. Touchpad still doesn't work in the new user.